# Problema com listas em JPA

Tags: java, jpa

**Estou iniciando com java e jpa, estou com um problema em entender algumas listas, estou fazendo um sistema que um Consumidor possui uma lista de Comandas, e cada comanda possui um consumidor, o problema é que quando eu quero buscar as comandas que o consumidor possui, o java me retorna uma lista vazia, eu não sei se estou errando em algo ou não entendi direito, será que conseguem me ajudar?**

```
##CONSUMIDOR
package com.ey;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_consumidor")
public class Consumidor {
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "consumidor", sequenceName = "sq_tb_consumidor" , allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "consumidor")
    @Column(name = "id_consumidor" , length = 9)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nr_completo_celular" , length = 14)
    private String celular;

    @Column(name = "nm_completo" , length = 100)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "ds_email" , length = 70)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "nr_cpf" , length = 14)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "ds_genero" , length = 30)
    private String genero;

    @Column(name = "dt_nascimento")
    private LocalDate dtNascimento;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "consumidor")
    private List<Comanda> comandas;

    // ----- Contructor & Getters & Setters

    /**
     * @param celular
     * @param nome
     * @param email
     * @param cpf
     * @param genero
     * @param dtNascimento
     */
    public Consumidor(String celular, String nome, String email, String cpf, String genero, LocalDate dtNascimento) {
        this.celular = celular;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.dtNascimento = dtNascimento;
    }
    
    public Consumidor(){

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return this.celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return this.genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public LocalDate getDtNascimento() {
        return this.dtNascimento;
    }

    public void setDtNascimento(LocalDate dtNascimento) {
        this.dtNascimento = dtNascimento;
    }

    public List<Comanda> getComandas() {
        return this.comandas;
    }

    public void setComandas(List<Comanda> comandas) {
        this.comandas = comandas;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Consumidor [celular=" + celular + ", comandas=" + comandas + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", dtNascimento="
                + dtNascimento + ", email=" + email + ", genero=" + genero + ", id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + "]";
    }

}
```

```
##COMANDA
package com.ey;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_comanda")
public class Comanda {
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "comanda", sequenceName = "sq_tb_comanda" , allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "comanda")
    @Column(name = "id_comanda" , length = 9)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nm_plano", length = 8)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "ds_metodo_pagamento", length = 17)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "nr_comanda", length = 6)
    private Integer numero;

    @Column(name = "vl_comanda")
    private Double valor;

    @Column(name = "dt_insercao")
    private LocalDate data;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comanda", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes;

    @ManyToOne
    private Estabelecimento estabelecimento;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_consumidor")
    private Consumidor consumidor;

    public Double somaTotal(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes){
        Double valorTotal = 0D;

        for (Movimentacao movimentacao : movimentacoes) {
            valorTotal = valorTotal + movimentacao.getQuantidade() * movimentacao.getBebida().getValor();
        }

        return valorTotal;
    }
 
    // ----- Contructor & Getters & Setters
    /**
     * @param nome
     * @param descricao
     * @param numero
     * @param valor
     */
    public Comanda(String nome, String descricao, Integer numero, Consumidor consumidor, Estabelecimento estabelecimento,LocalDate data, List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.consumidor = consumidor;
        this.estabelecimento = estabelecimento;
        this.data = data;
        this.valor = this.somaTotal(movimentacoes);
    }

    public Comanda (){
        
    }
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return this.descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Integer getNumero() {
        return this.numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public Double getValor() {
        return this.valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public LocalDate getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(LocalDate data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Estabelecimento getEstabelecimento() {
        return this.estabelecimento;
    }

    public void setEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento estabelecimento) {
        this.estabelecimento = estabelecimento;
    }

    public List<Movimentacao> getMovimentacoes() {
        return this.movimentacoes;
    }

    public void setMovimentacoes(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes) {
        this.movimentacoes = movimentacoes;
    }

    public Consumidor getConsumidor() {
        return this.consumidor;
    }

    public void setConsumidor(Consumidor consumidor) {
        this.consumidor = consumidor;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Comanda [consumidor=" + consumidor + ", data=" + data + ", descricao=" + descricao
                + ", estabelecimento=" + estabelecimento + ", id=" + id + ", movimentacoes=" + movimentacoes + ", nome="
                + nome + ", numero=" + numero + ", valor=" + valor + "]";
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma comanda existe sem um consumidor? Acho que nao, entao voce poderia tirar o manytoone e tambem tirar esse atributo :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "consumidor")
private List<Comanda> comandas;
```

Mas e como eu vou saber quais comandas sao de determinado consumidor? Simples, como voce esta mapeando muitas comandas para um consumidor assim:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_consumidor")
private Consumidor consumidor;
```

voce automaticamente sempre que cadastra uma comanda voce gera uma chave estrangeira na tabela, essa chave vai ta na coluna "id_consumidor"

Entao sempre que voce quiser todas as comandas de determinado usuario, voce deve criar uma query assim em jpa :

```
String jpql = "SELECT c "
        + "FROM Comanda c "
        + "WHERE c.id_consumidor =: id ";
```

Onde "id" seria um parametro passado no metodo